# Python Selenium Confirmation Dialog Clicking the confirmation button does not perform the action

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am having problems deleting notebooks in Zeppelin. I am trying to automate the debugging of the notes using Python Selenium.
The Python code I am using to test the deletion with a note is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as TM

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
control = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
control.implicitly_wait(10) #Cuando algo no aparece, prueba cada 1 seg. durante 20 seg. 
control.delete_all_cookies()

#WEB - LOGIN
url_del = "http://zeppelin_server:1919/#/notebook/2F7T7WPZP"
control.get('http://zeppelin_server:1919/#/')
wait = WebDriverWait(control, 10)

# Go to button
element = control.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[ng-click="navbar.showLoginWindow()"]')

#Clicking on the button to be selected
element.click()
wait = WebDriverWait(control, 30)
username_field = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'userName')))
password_field = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'password')))
login_button = control.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.btn.btn-default.btn-primary')

#Perform actions on the displayed elements
username_field.send_keys('user')
password_field.send_keys('password')

#Click on the button
login_button.click()
cookies = control.get_cookies()
wait = WebDriverWait(control, 10)

TM.sleep(5)
#Handling Cookies
for cookie in cookies:
    control.add_cookie(cookie)
control.get(url_del)    

TM.sleep(10)

# Find the button element by its class name or CSS selector
#button_element = control.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-default.btn-xs.ng-scope")
button_element = control.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[ng-click="moveNoteToTrash(note.id)"]')

# Click the button
button_element.click()
```

After that, when I click on delete note I get a confirmation dialog to delete the note with the following html code:

```
<div class="modal bootstrap-dialog type-primary size-normal in" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" id="49e1dec0-f885-4c33-9693-86a8d847ccc0" aria-labelledby="49e1dec0-f885-4c33-9693-86a8d847ccc0_title" tabindex="-1" style="display: block; padding-right: 17px; z-index: 1050;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="bootstrap-dialog-header">
                    <div class="bootstrap-dialog-close-button">
                        <button class="close" aria-label="close">×</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bootstrap-dialog-title" id="49e1dec0-f885-4c33-9693-86a8d847ccc0_title">Move this note to trash?</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="bootstrap-dialog-body">
                    <div class="bootstrap-dialog-message">This note will be moved to <strong>trash</strong>.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="bootstrap-dialog-footer">
                    <div class="bootstrap-dialog-footer-buttons">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" id="3124e67c-a4b2-42c1-859d-71c9140ff485">Cancel</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="9f9cea0d-b364-4ff5-85eb-02ea143e8fb2">OK</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I handle that in Python with the following code because ID is dynamic:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(control, 10)
ok_button = WebDriverWait(control, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.bootstrap-dialog-footer-buttons button.btn-primary')))
TM.sleep(10)
# Click the "OK" button
ok_button.click()

TM.sleep(10)
control.quit()
```

My user has delete privileges on all notes. I really don't know what else to do. I run the process manually, I run it in debug, I run it automatically and I check that the python ends by clicking the **OK** button in the dialog but the zeppelin note when I check it, it never sends it to the trash. Can anyone give me a recommendation? I have chatgpt and bard crazy, I can't find a way to automate my activity anymore.

Comment: The only problem is that you didn't specify the problem...

Comment: In addition I think this locator is way better and uniq: //*[@class="modal-footer"]//button[contains(text(),'OK')]

Comment: Where are you exactly stuck? Which line?